# TextFormField reset value after push and pop second screen

Tags: flutter

Firstly, sorry for my bad english, i have a screen with some TextFormFields, when i push a second screen, and click in back button, the TextFormFields in the first screen are clean.
How to solve this?

Comment: If you want to ask something here you have to provide some reproducible code here so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

I can't know your issue but try out this simple code and see if it help. Here everything is working as expected!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: FirstPage()
));

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(),
          FlatButton(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Text('Click me!'),
            onPressed: () =>
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute())),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Text('ok'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have customized your back button, when you going back don't use navigator.push, just use navigator.pop(context)

Answer (score 0):

Dears,

I found the problem, when put controller in my textformfield, he maintain the values when back from second screen.